# Tiling and Offset in Unity Shader Graph

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, shader

I'm trying to create a repeated stone material in Unity shader graph. applying the tiling and offest node changes the color of the texture rather than how often its repeated on a given axis. How to I repeat the texture of the material?

Answer (score 0):

Try creating a triplanar node and connceting the output of the tiling node to its tiling input. then connect the tripanar output to albedo.